# Print only changed values without the use of nested if statements

Tags: c++, architecture

I have four different sensors and store the value they record in a struct. Now I want to print these values every minute. But only the values that changed compared to the last print!

```
struct SensorData{
  uint8_t temp; //temperature
  uint8_t pres; //presure
  uint8_t hum; //humidity
  uint8_t fuel; //fuel
};
```

I solved this with 15 ifs. But this is kinda hard to read and debug. So I wounder if there is a better and more elegant way to solve this problem.

A table of all posabilitys: 1 if the value is different to the value before and 0 if they are the same:

[image]

This is how I solved it with the ifs at the moment:

```
if(storeData.temp != sensorData.temp && storeData.pres != sensorData.pres && storeData.hum != sensorData.hum && storeData.fuel == sensorData.fuel){
    //print case 1: temp,pres,hum
  }
  else{
    if(storeData.temp != sensorData.temp && storeData.pres != sensorData.pres && storeData.hum == sensorData.hum && storeData.fuel != sensorData.fuel){
      //print case 2: temp,pres,fuel
    }
    else{
      if(storeData.temp != sensorData.temp && storeData.pres != sensorData.pres && storeData.hum == sensorData.hum && storeData.fuel == sensorData.fuel){
        //print case 3: temp,pres,
      }else{
        if(storeData.temp != sensorData.temp && storeData.pres == sensorData.pres && storeData.hum != sensorData.hum && storeData.fuel != sensorData.fuel){
          //print case 4: temp,hum,fuel
        }else{
         ...
```

Like i mentioned I am looking for a way to solve this more elagant without the use of 15 ifs. Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't you do: if temp changed print temp; if pres changed print pres; etc.  Making sure you print any leading (time?) and trailing (newline?) info once.

Comment: Sorry this was kinda confusing from my side: With print I mean I send a String to my server with a line like this: `Particle.publish("S", String::format("0,%d,%d,%d,%d", sensorData.temp,sensorData.pres,sensorData.hum,sensorData.fuel),PRIVATE);´

Comment: So build the string to be sent incrementally, and then publish the data once.  The 'leading' data appears to be a `0,`; there doesn't appear to be 'trailing' data.  The basic idea reduces your 15 or 16 if statements into 4 simple tests on the data and one to check whether there's anything to publish.

Comment: When you call `Particle.publish("S", String::format("0,%d,%d,%d,%d", sensorData.temp,sensorData.pres,sensorData.hum,sensorData.fuel),PRIVATE);`, how does the server know which sensors' values are being sent if only two values had changed?

Comment: I don't see any need for 15 ifs

Comment: @flatmouse at the moment I thought to send the a extra value for that -> 0 to know that I send case 0. 1 to know I send case 1 and so on,.. and implement the rest on the server. Since this saves would save some data, which is my main aim to reduce the amount of data I send

Comment: so with the 4 if solutions I would need a way to calculate that number and send it with the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is just an enumeration of four bits representing the sensors. Hence you may have four comparisons and adjust the bits of a result accordingly:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct SensorData
{
    enum Index
    {
        Temperature = 3,
        Presure = 2,
        Humidity = 1,
        Fuel = 0
    };

    std::uint8_t temp; // temperature
    std::uint8_t pres; // presure
    std::uint8_t hum;  // humidity
    std::uint8_t fuel; // fuel
};

unsigned compare_sensors(const SensorData& a, const SensorData& b) {
    unsigned result = 0;
    result |= (a.temp != b.temp) << SensorData::Temperature;
    result |= (a.pres != b.pres) << SensorData::Presure;
    result |= (a.hum  != b.hum)  << SensorData::Humidity;
    result |= (a.fuel != b.fuel) << SensorData::Fuel;
    result = 15 - result; // adjust order
    return result;
}


#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    SensorData a = {};
    SensorData b = {};
    b.pres = 255;
    b.fuel = 255;
    std::cout << "Prssure/Fuel change is case " << compare_sensors(a, b) << ".\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use 4 `if`s:

```
std::string output;
char delimiter = ',';

//Check if data changed
if (storeData.temp != sensorData.temp)
    output += std::to_string(sensorData.temp) + delimiter;
if (storeData.pres != sensorData.pres)
    output += std::to_string(sensorData.pres) + delimiter;
if (storeData.hum != sensorData.hum)
    output += std::to_string(sensorData.hum) + delimiter;
if (storeData.fuel != sensorData.fuel)
    output += std::to_string(sensorData.fuel) + delimiter;

//Check if nothing changed
if (output == "")
    ;//Skip using 'return'?

//Remove 'delimiter' from last case
output.erase(output.length() - 1, 1);

//Send 'output'
//....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 4 `if` statements.
Check change in each variable separately, use `print` statement inside each `if` block.

*As per the constraints mentioned, I don't find any reason why you shouldn't do this.*

**If you want to print them in a single print statement:**
Use 4 `if` statements as mentioned above, and use 4 variables to hold the values from each `if` statement. Finally, print it in a single line.

Another method will be to build 'printing string' or 'number' step by step(start with an empty `string` and build it inside each if statement).

Comment: Please mention more details of your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays for storing the values, and a loop to check which array elements have changed. Rough outline in C (may contain errors, did not run it through a compiler):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
char *sensorNames[] = {"temp", "pres", "hum", "fuel"};
uint8_t sensorData[4];
uint8_t storeData[4];
int i;
bool first

while (1) {
  get_data(sensorData);
  first = true;
  for (i=0; i < sizeof(sensorData); i++) {
    if (sensorData[i] != storeData[i]) {
      // something changed
      if (!first) puts(", "); // add a comma if not first item in line
      printf("%s: %d -> %d", sensorNames[i], storeData[i], sensorData[i]);
      storeData[i] = sensorData[i]; // remember value
      first = false;
    }
  }
  if (!first) puts("\n"); // add a line feed if there were any changes
}
```

Additional advantage: adding a 5th or 6th sensor is trivial :-)